# Why does typescript not create objects properly?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

take the following code

```
type PersonKeys = "name" | "age"
type PersonR = Record<PersonKeys, string>

const test = (human: Partial<PersonR>): PersonR => {
    return {name: "", age: "", widen: true} // // fails perfect can't widen
}

const yolo = (k: PersonKeys) => {
    return test(CreatePair(k, new Date()));  // fails perfect, can't take anything but string
}

// Disgusting solution
const CreatePair = <T extends (number | string), A>(key: T, value: A): Record<T, A> => {
    return {[key]: value} as any;
}
```

The problem is simple, i want anything that returns a PersonR to not be able to widen to be able to take properties not on PersonR.

However i also want anything that takes a Partial of PersonR to only accept a VALID partial that means    {[K as keyof Person]: string} and not {[K as keyof Person]: Date}

This seems impossible without the hack of the CreatePair function.

Can you get both comments to still fail without using CreatePair?
why does using a object instead of CreatePair with a date value not cause it to fail?

Comment: Unclear to me exactly where you want an error and you are not getting it. Is this the case `test({[k]: new Date()});` ?

Comment: yeah to me that code in your comment should fail because iv'e specified PersonR can only have string types

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is simple, i want anything that returns a PersonR to not be able to widen to be able to take properties not on PersonR.

TypeScript is structural. You can always add properties. e.g. your example `widen` can be assigned quite easily:

```
type PersonKeys = "name" | "age"
type PersonR = Record<PersonKeys, string>

const test = {name: "", age: "", widen: true};
const fail: PersonR = test; // PASS
```

The only cases where it is an error is direct assignment (which is what your return statement is doing).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem. I don't like typescripts widening it leads to bugs, if i iterate over Object.keys(fail) it will now lead to bugs.

I wouldn't say all of my app doesn't allow widening but i would say 99% of is protected.  I need a way to not widen and to fail on Date

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, you want to ensure that when `test` is called the argument will have only the keys specified by `PersonR`. So these should all fail:

```
test({ [k]: new Date() }); // has a string indexer, because of the computed property  
let o = { name: "", age: "", widen: true };
test(o); // not a direct assigment of an object literal, so this is allowed
```

There isn't a general compiler switch to globally not allow such cases. One can argue that in principle there can't be such a switch, since in both cases the type of the argument is a structural subtype of the parameter type, so this should be allowed under OOP rules. The weird check from an OOP perspective is the excess property check since in this case we can't assign a structural subtype to it's super type (basically in this case we say that `let base:BaseType = new DerivedType()` is an error) .

That being said in the real world excess properties can be as sign of an error (hence the excess property check implemented in the compiler). While we can't forbid excess properties globally, we can forbid an argument to have excess properties using a conditional type. We use a generic type parameter to the function to get the actual type of the argument, and if this argument type has excess properties (or `string` indexers) we add a string literal type to the parameter type that will trigger an error:

```
type PersonKeys = "name" | "age"
type PersonR = Record<PersonKeys, string>

type StrictPropertyCheck<T, TExpected, TError> = Exclude<keyof T, keyof TExpected> extends never ? {} : TError;
const test = <T extends Partial<PersonR>>(human: T & StrictPropertyCheck<T, PersonR, "No extra properties!">): PersonR => {
    return {name: "", age: "", widen: true} // // fails perfect can't widen
}

const yolo = (k: PersonKeys) => {

    test({ [k]: new Date() }); // //error  
    let o = { name: "", age: "", widen: true };
    test(o); // error
}
```

Comment: Hello Titian, i agree with the things you've mentioned on structural typing however there are some things that still confuse me.

1: if you change new Date() to string in you're above code snippet it still fails.
2: If PersonR is a Record with string types (ONLY) why can it even accept a Date?
3: Why is it when an object literal is created with dynamic "k" which is a keyof PersonR the resulting object output type is [k: string]: sometype and not....
[k: PersonKeys]: sometype